Absolute value of difference between two numbers in the interval $(0,1)$ is in $(0,1)$
Pretty basic question that came up as a lemma in an analysis question I was doing. It is quite easy to see intutiively but formally proving it has given me a headache. I thought of using the triangle inequality, to get :
$$|y-x| < |1-x| + |1-y|$$
Wlog $x<y$ , then $1-y<1-x$, means
$$ |y-x| < 2|1-x|< 2(1-x)<2$$
I am trying to figure out how to get the tighter bound of '1' but I can't figure out how using only inequalities.

Note one number is greater than the other

Just write it as $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$ and then multiple the second by $-1$ to get $-1<-y<0,$ and add, giving: $$-1<x-y<1.$$

If the numbers are the same, then their difference is $0\not\in(0,1)$

Also simply assume $y-x\ge 1$ then $y\ge 1+x\ge 1$ contradiction. The negated statement  in this case is very easy to grasp.

$\left \vert x - \dfrac 12 \right \vert \lt \dfrac 12$ and $\left \vert \dfrac 12 - y \right \vert \lt \dfrac 12$, so by the triangle inequality: $$\vert x - y \vert = \left \vert \left (x- \dfrac 12 \right ) + \left (\dfrac 12 - y \right ) \right \vert \leq \left \vert x - \dfrac 12 \right \vert + \left \vert \dfrac 12 - y \right \vert \lt \dfrac 12 + \dfrac 12 = 1.$$  As noted in the comments, if $x=y$, then $\vert x-y \vert =0 \notin (0, 1)$, so the desired inclusion requires the additional assumption that $x \neq y$.
